# Vistadb SQL Syntax error

Tags: sql-server-2005, vistadb

vistadb4 not recognize this sql view script. but it is working with sql2005. is there a solution ? thanks.

```
SELECT DISTINCT ItemCode, SellingPrice
FROM         dbo.SalesPurchases AS a
WHERE     (KeyID =
                          (SELECT     TOP (1) MAX(KeyID) AS KeyID
                            FROM          dbo.SalesPurchases AS b
                            GROUP BY ItemCode, Type
                            HAVING      (ItemCode = a.ItemCode) AND (Type = 'purchase')))
GROUP BY ItemCode, SellingPrice
```

Comment: What error do you get, exactly?

Comment: not a VistaDB guy, but seems odd to do a SELECT DISTINCT on the same/only two columns that you have in the GROUP BY.  Typically GROUP BY means there's another aggregate column in the projection - like a average or count.  Haven't played with it, but also seems like your subselect could be unnecessary?

Comment: thanks :) these are the errors  Error 509 (Provider v. 4.2.18.1): Invalid or incomplete statement:  SELECT
Line #: 1; Column #: 1

________________________
ADDITIONAL INFORMATION:

Error 509 (Provider v. 4.2.18.1): Invalid or incomplete statement:  SELECT
Line #: 6; Column #: 29
Error 571 (Provider v. 4.2.18.1): HAVING can have only expressions which is in SELECT result or in GROUP BY 
Line #: 7; Column #: 65

Comment: Send this into Gibraltar Support and we can work with you to find the right query to get the result you want.

Answer (score 0):

not sure but take a look at this:

```
SELECT 
  DISTINCT a.ItemCode, a.SellingPrice
FROM         
  dbo.SalesPurchases AS a
JOIN
  (SELECT
     TOP (1) ItemCode, Type, MAX(KeyID) AS KeyID
   FROM
     dbo.SalesPurchases AS 
   GROUP BY 
     ItemCode, Type
   HAVING
     (ItemCode = a.ItemCode) AND (Type = 'purchase')
   ) b
   on b.KeyID = a.KeyID
GROUP BY 
  a.ItemCode, a.SellingPrice
```

Comment: thanks dude. its also not working :( I'm getting an error 

Error 509 (Provider v. 4.2.18.1): Invalid or incomplete statement:  SELECT
Line #: 1; Column #: 1

ADDITIONAL INFORMATION:

Error 509 (Provider v. 4.2.18.1): Invalid or incomplete statement:  SELECT
Line #: 6; Column #: 4
Error 569 (Provider v. 4.2.18.1): Expression is not present in GROUP BY clause:  ItemCode
Line #: 7; Column #: 14

Comment: forget about vistadb syntex :) Is there any mssql alternatives to this script?

Comment: wait a minute... you use both DISTINCT in SELECT clause and GROUP BY with the same fields list. It's redundant isn't it? try remove DISTINCT from top-level SELECT